# How to rotate UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm making a `UITableView` with expandable/collapsable cells for ios app. I put a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` on these cells but I'd like to make the arrow headed up/down when the cell is expanded/collapsed.

I found that it's possible to make a button with a custom image and change the button according to the state of the cell but it seems dirty to me because I don't need a button there and I have to add 2 images to the project (ok it's not that big but anyway).

So shouldn't it be better to simply rotate the existing  `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` ? and if so how can I do that?

Comment: Full discussion .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836606/use-table-view-disclosure-indicator-style-for-uibutton-ios

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not exactly what you want, but this the first thing I thought of. First, instantiate a button of type UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Next, rotate the button 90 degrees:

```
CGAffineTransform rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
rotationTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotationTransform, DegreesToRadians(90));
button.transform = rotationTransform;
```

Finally, use the button as the accessoryView:

```
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Does the use of DegressToRadians requires something special? My app doesn't compile anymore... Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_DegreesToRadians", referenced from:

Comment: Heh, I thought that one was pre-defined. `#define DegreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)` will work for this. You can put it at the top of your file. If you use it in more than one file, you should create a Conversions.h header and put the define in there.

Comment: yeah finally why not simply use radians directly? M_PI/2 is just fine.

Comment: I added a call to reload the current cell in didSelectRowForIndexPath: . Otherwise the arrow is not refreshed and doesn't change of sens

Comment: `button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0f);` is a bit neater.

Comment: Fantastic answer - annoyingly in iOS7 now, the UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure is the stupid "help symbol" !

Comment: But how to rotate UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator instead of the UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure icon?

Comment: But how to rotate UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator instead of the UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure icon?